# How many coloring schemes are there in this map?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

[image]

This map is painted in four colors. The colors of two adjacent areas cannot be the same. How many color schemes are there?

```
g = Graph[(Sort /@ 
     Flatten[Map[
       Thread[#[[1]] \[UndirectedEdge] #[[2]]] &, {{1, {2, 3}},
        {2, {1, 3, 4, 5}},
        {3, {1, 2, 5, 6}},
        {4, {2, 5, 7, 8}},
        {5, {2, 3, 4, 6, 7}},
        {6, {3, 5, 7}},
        {7, {4, 5, 6, 8}},
        {8, {4, 7}}}]]) // DeleteDuplicates, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

In addition, I am looking for a brute force enumeration algorithm.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for the chromatic polynomial.

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt.

Comment: @Ordinaryusers68 `ChromaticPolynomial[g, 4]` gives 480 four-colourings

Comment: `In[1329]:= ResourceFunction["FindProperColorings"][g, 4] // Length

Out[1329]= 480`

Answer (score 1):

```
data = Tuples[{1, 2, 3, 4}, 8];
samedata = (Sort /@ (Flatten[
       Outer[List, {#[[1]]}, #[[2]]] & /@ {{1, {2, 3}},
         {2, {1, 3, 4, 5}},
         {3, {1, 2, 5, 6}},
         {4, {2, 5, 7, 8}},
         {5, {2, 3, 4, 6, 7}},
         {6, {3, 5, 7}},
         {7, {4, 5, 6, 8}},
         {8, {4, 7}}}, 2])) // DeleteDuplicates;
sameQ[list_] := 
 If[AnyTrue[
   Table[SameQ @@ (list[[samedata[[i]]]]), {i, 1, Length[samedata]}], 
   TrueQ], False, True]
Select[data, sameQ[#] &] // Length
```